# Create navigation from all children of specified pagetype parent

Tags: silverstripe

I am creating a site with a holder page, and I want to create a shared navigation tree for this and all children. I have come up with a rather ugly solution and wondered if anyone had a better, cleaner solution?

As far as I can see there is a template method called 'InSection' but I believe this only matches a specified page, not page type.

```
<% with $Level(3) %>
    <% if $className == "fooHolder" %>
        <% with $Up %>
        <article>
            <nav id="contentNav">
                <ol>
                    <% with $Level(3) %><li><a href="$Link" title="$Title.XML">$MenuTitle.XML</a><% end_with %>
                        <% if $Menu(4) %>
                        <ol>
                            <% loop $Menu(4) %>
                                <li class="$LinkingMode"><a href="$Link" title="$Title.XML">$MenuTitle.XML</a>
                                    <% if $Children %>
                                        <ol>
                                        <% loop $Children %>
                                            <li class="$LinkingMode"><a href="$Link" title="$Title.XML">$MenuTitle.XML</a>
                                        <% end_loop %>
                                        </ol>
                                    <% end_if %>
                                </li>   
                            <% end_loop %>
                        </ol>
                        <% end_if %>
                    </li>
                </ol>               
            </nav>
            <section class="article-wrapper">
                $Content
            <section>
        </article>              
        <% end_with %>  
    <% else %>
        <% with $Up %>
               $Content
        <% end_with %>
    <% end_if %>
<% end_with %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have come up with a better solution, but always interested in hearing of any more.

in Page.php

```
public function parentFromPageType($pageType){

    if ($this->ClassName == $pageType) {
        $sectionRoot = $this;
    } else {
        $sectionRoot = $this->getAncestors()->filter(array(
            'ClassName' => $pageType
        ));
    }

    if ($sectionRoot ) {
        return $sectionRoot ;
    } else {
        return false;
    };
}
```

In Page.ss

```
<% if $parentFromPageType(CategoryIntroPage) %>
    <article>
        <nav id="contentNav">
            <ol>
                <% loop $parentFromPageType(CategoryIntroPage) %>
                    <li><a href="$Link" title="$Title.XML">$MenuTitle.XML</a>
                        <% if $Children %>
                            <% include NestedChildren %>
                        <% end_if %>
                    </li>   
                <% end_loop %>
            </ol>
        </nav>
        <section class="article-wrapper">
            $Content
        <section>
    </article>  
<% else %>
    $Content
<% end_if %>
```

In Includes/NestedChilden.ss

```
    <ol>
        <% loop $Children %>
            <li class="$LinkingMode"><a href="$Link" title="$Title.XML">$MenuTitle.XML</a>
                <% if $Children %>
                    <% include NestedChildren %>
                <% end_if %>
            </li>                       
        <% end_loop %>
    </ol>
</li>
```